# MVC async await for a long-running db insert/update

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, async-await

I have some code which imports a csv file and creates database records from the data. Using a standard synchronous approach this works fine, but large csv files can take a while to process.  Using async await, I'd like to have the csv processing run asynchronously so the user isn't stuck on the upload form until the processing is complete.

So the user would upload a file and immediately be transferred to a page which would display a message to indicate that the file was importing.

This is what I've tried.  This is my controller action that gets the form POST:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> UploadBulkImportFile(BulkUploadCsvModel model, HttpPostedFileBase file)
{
...
```

within this I call the functionality that I want to run asynchronously:

```
await Task.Run(() => testAsyncMethod(csvmodel));
```

The testAsyncMethod() does all the db crud operations involved in processing the csv.

```
public void testAsyncMethod(IEnumerable<List<csvmodel>>  model)
{
...
```

This code works but is no different to my previous synchronous code, i.e. the user still has to wait until the file is fully processed, so it's clearly not working properly.  Note that the code in testAsyncMethod() is NOT async code, just standard db calls - I'm wondering if that's where I'm going wrong.

Is this even possible in MVC? am I using async await for the wrong reasons?

Comment: That's not how async works...

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch - care to enlighten me?

Comment: Stephen's blog post he links to below clearly explains...  But, async allows the *SERVER* to continue doing other things, not the client (the web browser)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> So the user would upload a file and immediately be transferred to a page which would display a message to indicate that the file was importing.

That's not possible using asynchronous controller actions. This is because (as I describe on my blog) [`async` does not change the HTTP protocol](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/08/async-doesnt-change-http-protocol.html).

In your case, I'd recommend some JavaScript on the client to fire off the POST, *change the current page* to a "importing..." message, and then *update the same page* when the POST request completes.

And then remove the `async`/`await`/`Task.Run` from your controller action; it won't provide any benefit.

Comment: The real-time reporting is unimportant, I just want that particular bit of functionality to run asynchronously.  Your blog post was useful, in fact the part 'you can invent the notion of a "workflow" on the server: a POST call could create the workflow' sounds like what I want to do

Comment: Yes; that's actually a more complex solution, but certainly doable. In that case, you'd need to have a persistent queue (e.g., Azure queue / MSMQ) with an independent backend (e.g., Azure worker / Win32 service).

Comment: After doing a bit more research, I think that what I'm after is essentially a 'fire and forget' async call, although this is not without its downsides.

Comment: Keep in mind that on ASP.NET, "fire and forget" actually means "I don't care whether this code finishes executing", so I doubt it applies to an import scenario. That said, I have [another blog post](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/12/returning-early-from-aspnet-requests.html) that covers "fire and forget" on ASP.NET.